# python - calling variable from another function

Tags: python, function, variables

iam working on tkinter iam using filedialog to upload file my target is to have tow button.
button1 for uploading txt file
button2 is for processing the file see my current function setup

```
class procFile:
    def uploadFile(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def displayName(self):
        return self.filename

    def filePath(self):
        print("%s" %self.filename)

def main():
    upload = procFile()
    upload.uploadFile(filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(('txt', '*.txt'), ('All Files', '*.*'))))
    upload.filePath()
```

Please i need to another button to fireup another function which will access the variable from main function

Comment: I don't understand. You can access `upload.filename` from the main program.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, tkinter button needs function to fire up when i call the main function i get another open file prompt. i only need to access variable which the first button is loaded.

Comment: I can't see any Tkinter buttons in your code. Please consider posting a [mcve]. You need to explain more clearly what you want the program to do. BTW, `main` is conventionally the main entry-point to your program, so it should be called only once, after all the functions and classes have been defined. Of course, you don't have to do things that way, but it will be confusing to anyone reading your program if you call `main` more than once.

Comment: thanks @PM2Ring, this simple program will read txt file, it has brows button and process button.
i want to open a txt file with first button and second to process to read the file.
my buttons are:
browse=button(root, text="brows", command=main) 
process=button(root, text="process", command=process)
all i need now is function that will access variable from main to get the file path and process it.
i can do it by placing read function to my main function but i want to do this way.

Comment: You need to add that info to your question. Is your Tkinter GUI in a class? If you define the Button `command` functions as methods of that class they will be able to access the attributes of the class.

Comment: yes i have class, should it be starting like this?
process = Button(root, text="Process", command=processFile)

processFile():
         filein = upload.filename
         print(filein)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is dull in providing detail, here are two ways that results to what I understood of your question.

### **Method 1**

If you want to access the class variable in a function outside the class then:

```
class Class:
    # do something
    # example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 2
        print(self.var)

def outsideFunc():
    # operations you want to do
    # example:
    print(a.var * 3)
```

Result

```
>> a = Class()
2
>> outsideFunc()
6
```

Note that `outsideFunc()` can be defined anytime during the program. However, you can only call `outsideFunc()` after the class has been initialized.

The reason for this is because `filepath` is an instance of the class `procfile` which is only defined once the class is initialized. The period after the initialized class can be followed by various objects such as a function `Class.func()`, a variable `Class.var` or even a nested class `Class.subClass`

### **Method 2**

If you want to access the class variable inside the class then:

```
class Class:
    # do something
    # example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 4
        print(self.var)

    def func(self):
        # operations you want to do
        # example
        print(self.var + 5)
```

Result

```
>> b = Class()
4
>> b.func()
9
```

Just do the same what you have done before which is accessing the variable through `self.var` in the class.

### **Compare**

*Method 1* requires that when you call the class variable in an outside function, it has to be the same as the variable name you used to initialize the class. So when you do `a = Class()`, any function outside the class that refers to the initialized class will have to do `a.object` where object can be function, variable, or subclass.

*Method 2* requires the same thing. However, when the function inside the class is referring to one of it's variables, then it needs to use `self.object` where object can be function, variable, or subclass.

Both require that you initiate the class first with `varName = className()` in which varName is just a variable used to reference the class. Afterwards, you do as before with `varName.object`

Comment: thank alot method 2 fix my problem...

Comment: Glad to help, have a great day!